# Waring's problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

What is the best known quantitative upper bound for the quantity $G(k)$?

I know that it's due to Trevor Wooley and in simplest form states that 
$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \frac{G(k)}{k \log k} \le 1$.

I have been digging mathsci.net and I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 5):

At Trevor's [website](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematdw/bristol%20b16.pdf), I see $$G(k)\le k(\log k+\log\log k+2+o(1))$$

Comment: That talk is quite a few years old now; Trevor has made a lot of progress on such problems recently using efficient congruencing and I would not be surprised if better bounds were known. Certainly I recommend to the OP to look at the papers on Trevor's webpage.